# Confused by how to setup my .xcdatamodel for versioning

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4.6

I am reading the *Core Data Model Verisoning and Data Migration Programming Guide* and am confused on how to set up the initial verison number.

I have an existing app in which I did **not** set it up for Core Data versioning.  In addition, I am using Magical Record.  The current version of the app is 1.3; I am ready to release 1.4 with some minor changes, and I want to change one of the Core Data entities (add new attributes) in release 1.5.  I absolutely need versioning so my users will not lose any existing data.  I assume I must set up the current verison to enable Lightweight Versioning for release 1.5.

The question is: does the Core Data version have to match the app version?  or is that the common way for versioning to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magical record has a convenience method for this. In your AppDelegate where you setup magical record use.

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"storeName"];
```

Alternatively click on your core data .xcdatamodeld then top bar Editor > Add Model Version

Comment: Thank you so much... so do I still have to change version numbers manually, or does MR handle all of the changes (adding attributes) for me?  (afraid to try it without screwing something up)

Comment: No problem. When reading docs make sure you are on the master branch. https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/master ;-)

Comment: From what I have seen and tested it handles versioning for you. I am not 100% sure on this so maybe to be safe add a Model Version.

Comment: Does the Model Version have to match the app's version?

Comment: Nope, you might only decide to update your core data model in version 1.4 so it doesn't have to match.